# MSI applying transform removes signature

Tags: windows-installer, transform, digital-signature

I've run into a problem with digitally sign msi setups.

I sign my setup before shipping it, so the UAC recognize my certificate when the setup starts. But it seems to remove the signature once I apply a transform to this setup to provide it in other language.

It seems to me this is a correct behavior since the msi setup is modified after being signed.

Do you know any way to avoid this ? Keeping the msi signed after the transform.

I already thought about distributing my setup in different language in a all in one pack, but it will grow really fast (a setup for x64 and x86 in each language).

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .msi file itself should remain signed, but Windows Installer will correctly report that the installation is, collectively, unsigned. To have the aggregate treated as signed, sign the .mst file.